# Populate object from list of objects

Tags: c#, json

I have the following RootObject object which I need to populate.

```
public class Document2
{
    public string homecommunityid { get; set; }
    public string repositoryid { get; set; }
    public string documentuuid { get; set; }
    public string doctype { get; set; }
}
public class Document
{
    public Document2 document { get; set; }
}    
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Document> documents { get; set; }
}
```

I need to populate the RootObject object from a list of the following DocumentQuery Object.

```
public class DocumentQuery
{
        public string doctype { get; set; }
        public string homecommunityid { get; set; }
        public string repositoryid { get; set; }
        public string documentuuid { get; set; } 
}
```

I am trying to do something as follows:

```
RootObject doc = new RootObject()
   {
      Document= obj.Select(s => new Document()
      {
          document = new Document2()
             {
                 doctype = s.doctype
              }
       })
    };
```

I need this to be able JSON in this format:

```
    {
  "documents": [
    {
      "document": {
        "homecommunityid": "",
        "repositoryid": "",
        "documentuuid": "",
        "doctype": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried so far... The community will help you by refactoring it..

Comment: Why do you have two classes (`Document2` and `DocumentQuery`) which are essentially identical? Why do you then have an intervening type (`Document`) which appears to do nothing useful? Have you tried anything to populate a `RootObject` yet? It should be pretty simple with LINQ.

Comment: Back to basics. It's just a matter of `new`ing classes.

Comment: Done that. Been at  it all morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the following code, if you don't want to play with Reflection etc.:

```
List<DocumentQuery> queries = new List<DocumentQuery>();
// Fill queries
RootObject root = new RootObject();
foreach(var query in queries)
{
    Document document = new Document()
    {
        document = new Document2()
        {
            homecommunityid = query.homecommunityid,
            repositoryid = query.repositoryid,
            documentuuid = query.documentuuid,
            doctype = query.doctype
        }
    }
    root.documents.Add(document);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to resolve it.

AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another.